# Recipes for custom Block Entity isn't working, doesn't craft (1.20)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm writing a Minecraft based on tech and machines, and I'm making a furnace-esque machine for processing ores. However, I can't seem to get the recipes to work. Whenever I put the ore into the slot, nothing happens.

I added the inventory property to the watchlist and it showed that it was detecting the block in the right slot, but for some reason its not triggering crafting. I'm at a loss right now. I noticed that the getCurrentRecipe method is returning null (Optional.null), but I have no idea why as the inventory contains blocks. I also tried changing up some of the properties to see if it was a scope issue, but nothing seemed to work.

Also, there's no crashes at all. No errors thrown. It just doesn't do anything.

Here are some of the code snippets:

1. The .json files for the recipes

```
{
  "type": "darkcollective:ore_refining",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "item": "darkcollective:aernium_ore"
    }
  ],
  "output": {
    "count": 2,
    "item": "darkcollective:aernium_ingot"
  }
}
```

2. The code in the OreRefineryEntityClass that looks for the recipe and, if found, starts the crafting

```
private boolean hasRecipe() {
        Optional<OreRefineryRecipe> recipe = getCurrentRecipe();

        System.out.println(recipe);

        if(recipe.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        ItemStack result = recipe.get().getResultItem(getLevel().registryAccess());

        return canInsertAmountIntoOutputSlot(result.getCount()) && canInsertItemIntoOutputSlot(result.getItem());
    }

    private Optional<OreRefineryRecipe> getCurrentRecipe() {
        SimpleContainer inventory = new SimpleContainer(this.itemHandler.getSlots());
        for(int i = 0; i < itemHandler.getSlots(); i++) {
            inventory.setItem(i, this.itemHandler.getStackInSlot(i));
        }

        return this.level.getRecipeManager().getRecipeFor(OreRefineryRecipe.Type.INSTANCE, inventory, level);
    }
```

3. The code for the RecipeSerializer.

```
public static class Serializer implements RecipeSerializer<OreRefineryRecipe>{

        public static final Serializer INSTANCE = new Serializer();
        public static final ResourceLocation ID = new ResourceLocation(DarkCollective.ModID, "ore_refining");

        @Override
        public OreRefineryRecipe fromJson(ResourceLocation recipeId, JsonObject serializedRecipe) {
            ItemStack output = ShapedRecipe.itemStackFromJson(GsonHelper.getAsJsonObject(serializedRecipe, "result"));

            JsonArray ingredients = GsonHelper.getAsJsonArray(serializedRecipe, "ingredients");
            NonNullList<Ingredient> inputs = NonNullList.withSize(1, Ingredient.EMPTY);

            for(int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
                inputs.set(i, Ingredient.fromJson(ingredients.get(i)));
            }

            return new OreRefineryRecipe(inputs, output, recipeId);
        }

        @Override
        public @Nullable OreRefineryRecipe fromNetwork(ResourceLocation recipeID, FriendlyByteBuf buffer) {
            NonNullList<Ingredient> inputs = NonNullList.withSize(buffer.readInt(), Ingredient.EMPTY);

            for(int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
                inputs.set(i, Ingredient.fromNetwork(buffer));
            }

            ItemStack output = buffer.readItem();
            return new OreRefineryRecipe(inputs, output, recipeID);
        }

        @Override
        public void toNetwork(FriendlyByteBuf buffer, OreRefineryRecipe recipe) {
            buffer.writeInt(recipe.inputItems.size());

            for (Ingredient ingredient : recipe.getIngredients()) {
                ingredient.toNetwork(buffer);
            }

            buffer.writeItemStack(recipe.getResultItem(null), false);

        }
    }
```

Please note that I am new to modding, and I followed a tutorial for this code, so I don't really know code conventions yet.

If there's anything I missed, just tell me and I'd be happy to send.

Thank you!